# Lombok Customize SuperBuilder

Tags: java, lombok

I have two classes like this:

```
@Builder
public class Parent {
    final int a;
    final int b;

    public class static ParentBuilder {
        public ParentBuilder setAllTo(final int value) {
           return a(value).b(value);
        }
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
   final in c;

   @Builder(builderMethodName = "childBuilder")
   public Child(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
      super(a, b);
      this.c = c;
   }
}
```

My classes are growing up and got more and more fields.
And this is a reson to use the `@SuperBuilder`. But how can I add customized builder methods?

The same way dosent work. I tried this way:

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent { //yes, I want a abstract parent
    final int a;
    final int b;

    public class static ParentBuilder {
        public ParentBuilder setAllTo(final int value) {
           return a(value).b(value);
        }
    }
}


@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
   final in c;

}
```

### Edit

Its not possible yet. When I try to do it the same way, then I got a exception: `@SuperBuilder does not support customized builders. Use @Builder instead.`
The override is a inner class like this:

```
public abstract static class ParentBuilder<C extends ParentBuilder, B extends Parent.ParentBuilder<C, B>> {
    // custom imlementations here
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recently tried customizing `@SuperBuilder` using Lombok 1.18.8 and IntelliJ, and it worked fine. The only issue I faced was, I lost ability to use `toBuilder` flag in SuperBuilder - `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)`.

Below is the code to override @SuperBuilder methods.

```
public static abstract class ChildBuilder<C extends Child, B extends ChildBuilder<C, B>>
        extends ParentBuilder<C, B> {

    private LocalDate date;

    public B date(String dateStr) {
        this.date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr);
        return self();
    }
}
```

I added my working code here: [Customize SuperBuilder in Lombok](https://devnip.blogspot.com/2020/09/how-to-override-methods-of-superbuilder.html)

Comment: Add another method `public B date(LocalDate date)`, you can gain the ability `toBuilder` back.

Answer (score 8):

When `@SuperBuilder` was introduced in 1.18.2, customising it was not possible. If you try, Lombok 1.18.2 gives you the error message `SuperBuilder does not support customized builders.`

However, Lombok 1.18.4 added limited customisation possibilities of `@SuperBuilder`. (It's limited because you cannot modify setter methods, but you can add your own methods and modify `build()` and `builder()`.)

The generated `@SuperBuilder` code is quite complex and differs from `@Builder`. To avoid accidently messing up the generics-loaded builder code, you should start by copying the builder class header from the delombok output.
In your case (adding a new setter method), customize the abstract builder class `ParentBuilder` (and not the `ParentBuilderImpl`). Have a look at the delomboked code to find out how your setter should be defined, especially the return type.

This is the customized builder code for your example:

```
public abstract static class ParentBuilder<C extends Parent, B extends ParentBuilder<C, B>> {
    public B setAllTo(final int value) {
       return a(value).b(value);
    }
}
```

With Lombok 1.18.4, this compiles and works as expected.

Comment: Hm, currently the `@SuperBuilder` dont produce any code. It think its just a bug of lombok.

Comment: Do you use IntelliJ? The IntelliJ Lombok plugin does not yet support `@SuperBuilder` (see https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/513). However, it should work in Eclipse and using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. When I follow now your steps I got a compling-exception: `@SuperBuilder does not support customized builders. Use @Builder instead.`

Comment: Then you are not using the latest Lombok release 1.18.4.

Comment: Iam pretty sure, that Iam using 1.18.4.

Comment: If you now use Eclipse, have you also reinstalled the Lombok Eclipse plugin v1.18.4? It is not sufficient to just update the version in the pom.xml.

Comment: Nope, Iam still using `IntelliJ` and added the annotation-processor for maven and delegate the compiler to maven.

Comment: I just checked your example code using pure maven compilation and it works nicely with Lombok 1.18.4. The error message you pasted only exists in Lombok 1.18.2, but not in 1.18.4. So please double-check you use the correct version.

I added the example code that works for me to my answer.

Comment: In the POM was only `1.18.4`. Our company has mirror of MavenCentral - maybe is here a problem. I will check that tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182998/discussion-between-jan-rieke-and-user6537157).

Comment: Are there any better solution in 1.18.6 or still the same?

Comment: There have been only bugfixes to `@SuperBuilder` since 1.18.4. What do you want to do? Because concerning the use-case of this question, I cannot imagine a better solution.

Comment: This worked great for me! Great solution and approach for handling the generic-laden lombok @SuperBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning, that if you want to customize child class builder, the custom builder has to inherit from the parent builder (whether or not the parent builder was customized):

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {
    ...
}

@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
    ...
    public static class ChildBuilder<C extends Child, B extends ChildBuilder<C, B>> extends ParentBuilder<C, B> {
        ...
    }
}
```