# How to update field in java gracefully?

Tags: java, lombok

```
@Data
public class MyData {
    private long a;
    private long b;
    private long c;
}
```

if we want to update all the field of a,b,c, then code could be like below:

```
MyData d;
...
d.setA(d.getA()+2);
d.setB(d.getB()+5);
d.setC(d.getAC()+8);
```

in other language, we may write code like:

```
d.a += 2;
d.b += 5;
d.c += 8;
```

Any graceful way to do update with this mode in java?

Comment: With pure Java, make your fields public, then you can increment them like that. No idea whether that upsets Lombok.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all technically correct, but to give some conceptual thoughts: what you are thinking of/asking for is called [Uniform Access Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) - the idea that reading and writing to a field follows the same syntax. Respectively the idea that `x.y` and `x.y()` can actually mean the same thing.

And for good or bad, Java does **not** support that concept on the syntactical level, and lombok doesn't help here either.

If you want to assign a value to a field, you either need an explicit setter (or maybe increment) method, or you need to make the field `public`.

End of story.

Answer (score 1):

While you could make your fields public:

```java
public class MyData {
    public long a;
    public long b;
    public long c;
}
```

and then just

```java
MyData d;
//...
d.a += 2;
d.b += 5;
d.c += 8;
```

a better approach would be to introduce increment methods:

```java
public class MyData {
    private long a;
    private long b;
    private long c;

    public void incrementA(long x){
        a += x;
    }

    public long incrementAndGetA(long x){
        a += x;
        return a;
    }

    public void incrementB(long x){/*...*/}

    public long incrementAndGetB(long x){/*...*/}

}
```

and then...

```java
MyData d;
//...
d.incrementA(2);
long bb = d.incrementAndGetB(4);
```

This approach will maintain [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).
Obviously you can add *decrement* methods (or just use negative values).

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function about that.

```
@Data
public class MyData {
    private long a;
    private long b;
    private long c;

    void add(long number1, long number2, long number3){
       a += number1;
       b += number2;
       c += number3;
    }
}
```

You can also use negative numbers for extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a dedicated method:

```
public class MyData {
    private long a;
    ...

    // use setter to set value
    public void setA(long value){
       this.a = value;
    }
    // add to current value
    public void addToA(long value){
       this.a += value;
    }
    ...
}
```

You could also make those fields public, it comes to your choice.

But methods can do more things, like validate input values. It's also a way of encapsulating values inside of the class, and let smart methods to modify their values.

You can also modify Lombok builder to have a custom setter. You can find a thread on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379899/use-custom-setter-in-lomboks-builder/42380017)

```
  @Builder
  class MyData {
     ....
  public static class MyDataBuilder {
        public MyDataBuilder a(long value) {
            this.a = value;
            return this;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an access method

```
public void manipulateX(Function<Integer, Integer> manipulator) {
  x = manipulator.apply (x);
}
```

You can then call that with `mc.manipulateX(i -> i+ 2)`.