# Add custom methods to Lombok @Builder

Tags: lombok

Given the following Lombok-annotated class:

```java
@Builder
public class User {

    private String username;
}
```

I created a utility class for creating `User` objects in tests:

```java
public class UserTestUtils {

    public static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "Foo Bar";

    public static User.UserBuilder aDefaultUser() {
        return User.builder().username(DEFAULT_USERNAME);
    }
}
```

Now I can call this in my test:

```java
User user = aDefaultUser().build();
```

I'd like to enrich this utility class with a method which does not return a `User` object but a JSON string representation like this:

```java
User user = aDefaultUser().toJsonString();
```

Is it possible to add a custom `toJsonString()` method to the `User.UserBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just define a static class named `UserBuilder`, and lombok will add the methods:

```java
    @Builder
    public class User {
    
        private String username;
    
        public static class UserBuilder {
    
            String toJsonString() {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

If you inspect the generated code, you will find:

```java
    public static class UserBuilder {
        @Generated
        private String username;

        String toJsonString() {
            return "";
        }

        @Generated
        UserBuilder() {
        }

        @Generated
        public UserBuilder username(final String username) {
            this.username = username;
            return this;
        }

        @Generated
        public User build() {
            return new User(this.username);
        }

        @Generated
        public String toString() {
            return "User.UserBuilder(username=" + this.username + ")";
        }
    }
```

The mechanism is similar to [defining custom setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379899/use-custom-setter-in-lomboks-builder)